# Encrypted fruits

Tags: rebus, emoji

Haven't been making a puzzle for a long time, this is a simple puzzle: figure the fruits with the given clues.

> 1. b->a,aeiou->? A
> 2. 3-3 $[3,\infty)$
> 3. ✋-i  Tesla
> 4. $^{12}X$  $\boxed{^{4}}$ (️ - 5 + $\boxed{^9}$) $x=0$
> 5. Due: ️
> 6. -t fruit
> 7. $y=xe^x\rightarrow ???$ out $\times$ ??
>    -Wa e-?(✉️) Off $\times$ ??
> 8. $\boxed{15}$ $\Omega-\boxed{31}$
> 9. 磷
> 10. $6.02\times10^{23}$
> 11. 2.718
> 12. ️
> 13. $\aleph_{0\leftarrow}$ tS
> 14. $\boxed5$
> 15. No$\times$??

Every space means a different clue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a Community Wiki to group-solve this...

1. b->a,aeiou->? A

> **BANANA**, BAN + AN (used before vowels as "a" is used before "b") + A
>  (@Stiv and @samm82)

2. 3-3 $[3,\infty)$

> **ORANGE** = 0 + RANGE (@SteveV)

3. ✋-i  Tesla

> **WATERMELON** = (WAIT - i) + ERM + ELON (@samm82)

4. $^{12}X$  $\boxed{^{4}}$ (️ - 5 + $\boxed{^9}$) $x=0$

> **CRANBERRY** = C[<sup>12</sup>C is carbon isotope] + RAN + Be + [(RIVER - FIVE + F)=(RR)] + Y [x=0 is y axis] (@long)

5. Due: ️

> **DURIAN** = almost soundalike of DUE + RAIN (@Stiv)

6. -t fruit

> **STARFRUIT** = STAR(-t) + FRUIT (@GarethMcCaughan)

7. $y=xe^x\rightarrow ???$ out $\times$ ??
   -Wa e-?(✉️) Off $\times$ ??

> **[WINTER MELON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_gourd)** = [W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) + IN + (WATER - WA) + MAIL (soundalike to "mel") + ON (@samm82)

8. $\boxed{15}$ $\Omega-\boxed{31}$

> **POMEGRANATE** = P (Phosphorus = element 15) + OMEGA - GA (Gallium = element 31) + GRENADE (soundalike) (@Stiv)

9. 磷

> **PEAR** = [Phosphorus](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%A3%B7) (P) + EAR  (@Stiv)

10. $6.02\times10^{23}$

> **AVOCADO** = vague soundalike for [Avogadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) (@Stiv)

11. 2.718

> **PINEAPPLE** = PIN + e + APPLE (@Stiv)

12. ️

> **KIWI** = KEY + WE (@Stiv)

13. $\aleph_{0\leftarrow}$ tS

> Possibly **COCONUTS** = **CO**ld + **CO**ld + aleph **NU**ll + **TS** (@Stiv)

14. $\boxed5$

> **RAMBUTAN** = Ram + **B**oron + Orang**utan** (@SteveV)

15. No$\times$??

> **PAPAYA** = PAPA + YA (as in 'yes', opposite (symbolised by 'x' throughout this puzzle) to 'No') (@Stiv)

Comment: I wonder whether the flag in 6 is meant to be for the rot13(FGNEG bs n enpr), though usually such flags are rectangular rather than triangular, making that one rot13(FGNE SEHVG).

Comment: And obviously 14 is some kind of rot13(BENATR) since rot13(gur ynfg rzbwv vf na BENAT) but I haven't any good ideas for what kind.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Might be worth a shout - I'm not seeing anything from a synonym for 'flag' for that one right now...!

Comment: For 15 rot13(ln pbhyq or gur bccbfvgr bs ab sbe cncnln, ohg vg'f n fgergpu)

Comment: Super not sure about this one, but 4 might be a rot13([ZNEVBAOREEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marionberry) = Zt (zntarfvhz) + EHA (fbhaqnyvxr) + OR (orelyyvhz) + (EVIRE - I) + S (syhbevar) + EBBG (n fbyhgvba gb na rdhngvba, fbhaqnyvxr) = ZNEVBAOREEL SEHVG - Abg fher nobhg "sehvg" ng gur raq, gubhtu)

Comment: Number 4 is rot13(Penaoreel: 12P vf gur zbfg pbzzba vfbgbcr bs Pneoba, 4 naq 9 ner gur ngbzvp ahzoref sbe Or naq S. Fb P + ena + Or + (EVIRE - SVIR + S =>EE) + L (k=0 vf gur L nkvf)

Comment: @long That sounds way better than mine lol

Comment: just curious, where do the points go on a community wiki?

Comment: @SteveV Nowhere! They don't earn points for anyone because it's a group effort :)