# Another encrypted things

Tags: rebus, science, emoji

Inspired by encrypted [fruits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107822/encrypted-fruits) and [vegetables](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107849/encrypted-vegetables), this simple puzzle encrypts a set of things having a common topic. So, please, figure out the topic itself (unlike the linked questions, clues are comma-separated here unless the commas are within parentheses, braces etc.):

> 1. , $\boxed{6}+\alpha\to?$
> 2. $\dfrac{F}{x}$,
> 3. $\boxed{83}$,
> 4. $\boxed{19}$, $(v_4-v_1)$
> 5. $0.0075\ \mathrm{mmHg}$, [0], $\{0,1,2,...\}$
> 6. $I^2Rt$, $\boxed{92}$, $\approx7.38906$, $0.10197\ \mathrm{kgf}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These rebuses resolve as follows:

1. , $\boxed{6}+\alpha\to?$

> **ROOK** = ROCK, changing C (element#6 = Carbon) to O by adding 12 alphabet positions (alpha - this element's atomic number - is 12) *[NB OP's intent was that Carbon plus an alpha particle becomes Oxygen, i.e. C becomes O]*

2. $\dfrac{F}{x}$,

> **KNIGHT** = K (F=kx, Hooke's Law) + NIGHT

3. $\boxed{83}$,

> **BISHOP** = Bi (element#83 = Bismuth) + SHOP

4. $\boxed{19}$, $(v_4-v_1)$

> **KING** = K (element#19 = Potassium) + (possibly) ENG, performing some kind of **v**owel manipulation I can't quite pinpoint...?

5. $0.0075\ \mathrm{mmHg}$, [0], $\{0,1,2,...\}$

> **PAWN** = Pa (Pascal) + W (0th element of **W**INDOW) + N (the set of natural numbers)

6. $I^2Rt$, $\boxed{92}$, $\approx7.38906$, $0.10197\ \mathrm{kgf}$

> **QUEEN** = Q (Joule's Law) + U (element#92 = Uranium) + EE (7.38906 is approximately e squared) + N (Newton)

All of these are:

> **CHESS PIECES**!

Comment: Wow you solved it all before I attached a community wiki

Comment: Great! However, the intended solution for 1 was a bit different, namely rot13(nqqvat nycun cnegvpyr gb pneoba cebqhprf bkltra). Also for 5, rot13(gur rzbwv vf "jvaqbj", naq gnxvat mrebgu ryrzrag [0] bs "jvaqbj" vf "j").

Comment: @trolley813 Aha, okay, that makes more sense! I'll amend my answer, and see if I can nail down 4 completely too...

Comment: Well, the intended meaning for 4 was rot13(va Ratyvfu tenzzne (urapr gur HX synt), I4 qrfvtangrf cerfrag cnegvpvcyr bs n ireo (r.t. ernqvat), naq I1 vf vasvavgvir (r.t. ernq). Fhogenpgvat I1 sebz I4 (bs gur fnzr ireo) yrnirf "vat" fhssvk (gung'f gehr sbe zbfg ireof)).